# Search with for values with a loop

Tags: c#, loops, search, while-loop

I am trying to make a code that will search for a custom value , entered by the user .
My knowledge with C# is not so big so the easiest way for me would be to search with a loop when its possible .

The code so far :

```
 private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     uint offset = 0x0154d6e4;
     uint value= 844705;
     uint randBuff = Loaded_DLL.Extension.ReadUInt32(offset);

     while (randBuff == value)
     {
         offset = (offset + 4);
         listBox1.Items.Add(randBuff.ToString("x8")); 
     }        
 }
```

In my brain I think like the start offset is `unit offset` from this point it start to search for the value `uint value` , to get the value out from the memory it read it with my DLL from the entered offset `Extension.ReadUInt32(offset);` . 
Maybe one time the program will find the value and will output it, in the listbox1. When it's not found the offset will be increased by 4. Somehow its not working or not searching, I am not sure what's the right answer.

Comment: The three local variables are initially assigned in a way where the value of `offset` is somehow used to find the initial value of `randBuff`. But that does not mean that those two variables stay "connected" or "entangled". They are separate and independent. The `while` loop changes only `offset`, but `offset` is not used in the loop criterion, only the other two local variables. So how did you **want** your `while` loop to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     uint offset = 0x0154d6e4;
     uint value= 844705;
     uint randBuff = Loaded_DLL.Extension.ReadUInt32(offset);

     while (randBuff != value)
     {
         offset = (offset + 4);
         randBuff = Loaded_DLL.Extension.ReadUInt32(offset);

     }
     if(randBuff == value)
         listBox1.Items.Add(randBuff.ToString("x8"));
     else
        listBox1.Items.Add("Value not found!");
 }
```

You needed to read the new offset in the randBuff.

Comment: I don't think this code is what they're actually going for. For one thing the loop condition seems incorrect. For another it's adding to the listbox with ever iteration, which doesn't seem to be what they want.

Comment: It's not working , since it's not allowed to use one variable with the same name twice :( . EDIT1:upps :) copied it with uint no more errors

Answer (score 0):

the code doesn't keep updating its randbuff so will get stuck... so the code should be something like :-

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     uint offset = 0x0154d6e4;
     uint value= 844705;
     uint randBuff = Loaded_DLL.Extension.ReadUInt32(offset);

     while (randBuff == value)
     {
         offset = (offset + 4);
         listBox1.Items.Add(randBuff.ToString("x8")); 
         randBuff = Loaded_DLL.Extension.ReadUInt32(offset)
     }        
 }
```

however, from your description, I'm not sure if the while loop is right, currently it will keep looking as long as the value read is 844705.... so all the values in the listbox will be the same.   I'm thniking maybe you want to keep searching until you find the value.... then you'd use....

```
while (randBuff != value)
```

however I'm not quite sure of your intention.

Comment: What does != mean ? Now I am not sure if I get it right from the msdn page .Does == means equal and != not equal ?!
But yes I only want to search until the value is found .

Comment: !=  is not equal, and if thats the case, you want to use !=.   ie, while the randbuff is not equal to value, add the radbuff to the listbox, move the offset by 4, and get the next randbuff.

Comment: I need exactly the opposite of this , when the value matches randBuff then add it to the listbox .